Winforms ReportViewer's SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout) is slow
I have a C# Winforms application where we show SSRS reports in ReportViewer. Normally it works completely fine without any issue. For a new report, I had to change the Display Mode to PrintLayout as it was not rendering correctly in Normal Mode. But changing the Display Mode seems to take additional time, anywhere from 30 seconds
to 1-2 minutes, but without changing the DisplayMode it renders within 1-2 seconds.
Does anyone know why changing the display mode takes additional time?
Is there a way to set the default Display Mode to PrintLayout always, so the report is rendered in PrintLayout mode instead of Normal?
rptViewerMgmtReport.RefreshReport();

rptViewerMgmtReport.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
rptViewerMgmtReport.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;

